# How can I update a model field based on updating another model's field using Signals?

Tags: django, signals

I am trying to add all the `total` values in `Transaction` model and put them in the `Sale` model's first instance (`pk=1`) `gross_total` field. Here is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    gross_total = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.gross_total)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey('Sale')
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        self.total = self.price * self.quantity
        return super(Transaction, self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.total)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import Sum

from .models import Transaction, Sale

@receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
def update_sale(sender, **kwargs):
    sale = Sale.objects.get(pk=1)
    sale.gross_total = Transaction.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum']
    sale.save()
```

I am new to using Django Signals. What is it that I am doing wrong? If I save an instance of `Transaction` model the `Sale` model data doesn't get updated!

Comment: Have you imported your `signals.py` in `ready()` function in your AppConfig as suggested in "Where should this code live?" box in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions ?

Comment: @Nikita I didn't do that. I've read the signals chapter in the documentation but it's not very clear to me. Can you help in this regard?

Comment: @Nikita Ok I got this to work copying codes from another blog but I have no idea how it works! Can you suggest me an easy reading material?

Comment: I have no idea about easy reading material unfortunately, and I agree that Django docs in parts range from crystal clear explanation to 'wtf am I reading' :). However I tried to explain some in additional answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following changes to my app to get it to work.

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'alpha.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Now create an apps.py inside my application.

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'alpha'
    verbose_name = 'Alpha'

    def ready(self):
        import alpha.signals
```

I don't have any idea how all this is working though, lol.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is...

When you write code in `signals.py` it's a valid code, but it's never run, untill this module is executed directly (not intended use though in this case) or imported. So it must be imported somewhere in order for code to be run and handler functions be registered to corresponding signals.

When your Django project is ran, Django creates application registry from apps declared in your `settings.py`. While creating a registry it imports every package and module declared in `settings.py`and also calls several predefined functions during this process including `ready()` inside every `AppConfig`.

When importing a package in Python the code inside special file `__init__.py` is executed automatically by Python internals, usually it allows to define special behavior and properties for a package.

So basicly, this leads to:

1. Django project is launched.
2. Django reads `settings.py` and finds your App as one of declared ones.
3. Django imports your App package, the code inside `__init__.py` is ran and `default_app_config` is specified. Now Dgango knows it.
4. When processing of all apps has finished, Django calls `ready()` function for every `AppConfig` found during previous steps.
5. `ready()` in `MyAppConfig` is run and your `signals.py` module gets imported.
6. During this import, the code inside `signals.py` is executed: your `update_sale` function is created and `@receiver` decorator is executed with it as argument.
7. The `receiver` decorator code while being executed registers `update_sale` function to be run on `post_save` signal emitted by `Transaction` model class.