# Django How to update some specific fields data after input from another model using signals

Tags: django, django-signals

I have some problem with django signals. I wanna update PermohonanWP  status model fields from 'PROSES' to 'SUCCESS' after I Input data to PenelitiPemindahanWP. (Suppose i have already input data to PermohonanWP model with status = 'PROSES')

here my model.py

```
class PermohonanWP(models.Model):
      npwp = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
      nama = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
      status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class PenelitiPemindahanWP(models.Model):
      permohonan_pemindahan = models.ForeignKey(PermohonanWP, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      nomor_lhp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      nomor_st = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

here my signals i input it in model.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PenelitiPemindahanWP, dispatch_uid="update_permohonan_id")
def update_permohonan(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pemohon = PermohonanWP.objects.get(id=instance.permohonan_pemindahan)
    pemohon.status = "SUCCESS"
    pemohon.save()
```

I wanna update the status field from PermohonanWP but whenever i submit saved button, it not saved and not update the fields.

Comment: Could you clarify what is wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: im new to programming django, i just wanna input data to PenelitiPemindahanWP models, and i just wanna tell another user that status Proses is Finished when PenelitiPemindahanWP is Filled. So i used ForeignKey in my PenelitiPemindahanWP that refer to PermohonanWP. now i wanna change status from Proses to Success in PermohonanWP but i fail. I think using the signals is the answer, or maybe im wrong in implementation.

Comment: Did you update `apps.py` file with `from django.apps import AppConfig
class StoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = '<app name>'
    def ready(self):
        import <app name>.signals`

Comment: i try your guide @AvishkaDambawinna to update my apps.py now i can save the data but the status fields in PermohonanWP still not updated. I used Prakhar code below but the status still 'Proses', nothing change

Comment: You need to pass id `pemohon = PermohonanWP.objects.get(id=instance.permohonan_pemindahan.id)`

Comment: In the `StoreConfig` class, the **Store** should be replaced with your app name. First letter capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this

```
pemohon = PermohonanWP.objects.get(id=instance.permohonan_pemindahan)
```

to

```
pemohon = PermohonanWP.objects.get(id=instance.permohonan_pemindahan.id)
```

**OR**

Even simply :

```
pemohon = instance.permohonan_pemindahan
```

Comment: I already changed it but nothing happend to my status Fields in PermohonanWP, it's value still 'Proses'

Comment: thank you men, your code works very well

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your signals in [`apps config ready method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/) [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112157/8388057)

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class <App_name>Config(AppConfig):
    name = '<app name>'

    def ready(self): 
        import <app name>.signals
```

**init**.py

```
default_app_config = '<app_name>.apps.<App_name>Config'    # first letter capital
```

and your signal should look like,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PenelitiPemindahanWP, dispatch_uid="update_permohonan_id")
def update_permohonan(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pemohon = PermohonanWP.objects.get(id=instance.permohonan_pemindahan.id)
    pemohon.status = "SUCCESS"
    pemohon.save()
```

Hope it works.

---

**Tip**:

It will be better if you use choices for your status field.

> In my opinion, whenever it’s possible integers should be used for storing information about some resource status. There is a big advantage of such a solution. After adding a database index to that field, search performance will be more efficient when using an integer field instead of a char field.  Another advantage is the fact that we can manipulate ordering in such a field. For example:
> In the model there is a status field with the allowed choices:
> New = 1, Draft = 2, Published = 3.
> If we want to order those Django models instances by status from the new created to published, we can now easily add order on that field (ascending on integer field). [ref](https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-models-declaring-list-available-choices-right-way/)

One approach;

models.py

```
    ...
    # status
    PENDING = 1
    PROCESSING = 2
    DELIVERED = 3
    CANCELED = 4

    ORDER_STATUS = [
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (PROCESSING, 'Processing'),
        (DELIVERED, 'Delivered'),
        (CANCELED, 'Canceled')
    ]

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS, default=PENDING)
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks men,i was wrong in signals implementation, and then i found this reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110883/how-can-i-update-a-model-field-based-on-updating-another-models-field-using-sig?rq=1, it tell me that i must add some code to __init__.py : default_app_config = 'pwptmk_app.apps.PwptmkAppConfig' and then add apps.py like u said. And it's Gonna Work. Thanks  a Lot for the answer. Im so happy, it's like magic for noob like me